# Coordinate system of android.graphics.Camera?

Tags: android, canvas, camera, coordinate-systems

I have to use Camera to draw some things in Canvas.But I can not detect that coordinate system of Camera is `Right hand` or `Left hand`.I tested Translation and it was seemed that is `Left hand`,but when I rotate bitmap around Y axis,it rotates like `Right hand` and I do not understand what is the problem.

Comment: Did you get any information on this ?

Comment: @Anukool NO.I did not found any answer.